# Number of elements in Haskell in pointfree style

Tags: haskell, filter, pointfree

I want to define a function that computes the number of elements in a list that satisfy a given predicate:

```
  number_of_elements :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
  number_of_elements f xs = length (filter f xs)
```

For example:

```
  number_of_elements (==2) [2,1,54,1,2]
```

should return *2*.

We can write it shorter:

```
  number_of_elements f = length . filter f
```

Is it possible to write it without *f* parameter?

Comment: What your are looking for is called "Pointfree style". There is a wiki about it here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree . It teaches you all the tricks like the owl: `((.)$(.))` and the dot: `((.).(.))`. I wouldn't personally recommend this style though.

Comment: I would recommend playing around with it a bit, to see how it works, but using the partially pointfree style `number_of_elements f = length . filter f`. That's the most readable usually.

Comment: This is a function I would rarely bother defining, because `length (filter f xs)` is, frankly, easier to read than `number_of_elements f xs`.  The latter requires me figure out what your function does by either looking up your function definition, documentation or inferring it from the type; while the former is a straightforward combined use of two functions I understand already—and it's also shorter to write!  I would only define this as an auxiliary function in a `where` binding, or as an unexported module function—and even then only if it's going to be the argument to other functions.

Comment: sacundim is quite correct. If you *really* want something more than `length (filter f xs)`, I'd suggest defining the `(.:)` combinator in is7s's answer, and using `length .: filter` as needed, but even that is a bit silly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
number_of_elements = (length .) . filter
```

Comment: Thanks, and can you explain why `(length . filter)` or `(length $ filter)` won't work?

Comment: @vikingsteve, well, `length . fitler` expands to `\x -> length (filter x)`. Here `filter x` is a function and you can't compute length of a function, whatever that would mean. Similarly, `length $ filter` is trying to compute length of the `filter` function.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can get more readable than the what you suggested. However, just for the fun of it you can do this:

```
numberOfElements = (.) (.) (.) length filter
```

or

```
(.:) = (.) . (.)
numberOfElements = length .: filter
```

Comment: `(.*)` is usually called `(.:)`; [lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot) calls it that, for instance.

Comment: @C.A.McCann maybe because (.) is one-character shorter? :)

Comment: I personally prefer `.*` in fact I uploaded a dumb package to hackage (the "composition" package) that defines it under `Data.Composition`

Comment: A wonderful property of the semantic editor combinator style--`fmap.fmap` or `result.result`--is that it consistently composes. If you want to go three levels deep, just add a third `fmap` or `result` (or a `first`, `second`, etc). In contrast, the `fmap fmap fmap` becomes something quite different when you add or remove `fmap`s.

Answer (score 6):

You might like to read about [Semantic Editor Combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators). Take the `result` combinator from there:

```
result :: (output -> output') -> (input -> output) -> (input -> output')
result = (.)
```

The `result` combinator takes a function and applies it to the result of another function. Now, looking at the functions we have:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
length :: [a] -> Int
```

Now, `length` applies to `[a]`'s; which, it happens, is the result type of functions of the form `foo :: [a] -> [a]`. So,

```
result length :: ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> Int)
```

But the result of `filter` is exactly an `[a] -> [a]` function, so we want to apply `result length` to the result of `filter`:

```
number_of_elements = result (result length) filter
```

Comment: I'd rewrite that last line to isolate the composed SEC (semantic editor combinator): `number_of_elements = (result.result) length filter`. Read as: compute the number of elements by applying `length` to the result of the result of `filter`. Here `(result.result)` is the editor combinator and `length` is the (semantic) editor. Definitely read the [SEC post](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators).